# Angular / MomentJS - Binding formControlName to md-datepicker

Tags: angular, momentjs

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Moment.js
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- When returning the date timestamp from firebase, i convert it back to a valid / readable date
- For my HTML input field (mdDatePicker) to display the returned and converted date.

**Issue**

- When using the 'formControlName', the same way I successfully use it for all my other text / checkbox inputs, I receive the following error:

> ERROR Error: Datepicker: value not recognized as a date object by DateAdapter

**Questions**

1. How do I take my returned value and make the date picker show it?

**HTML**

```html
 <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" formControlName="album_date" required />
<label class="vs__input__label">  Date </label>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

**Component TS**

```js
var timestamp = albumToDisplay.album_date;
var albumDate = moment.unix(timestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
       

this.albumDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  album_title: [albumToDisplay.album_title],
  album_date: [albumDate]
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

- After reading here [enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6265) I updated material.
- The error I now receive is the following:

> ERROR Error: Datepicker: Value must be either a date object recognized by the DateAdapter or an ISO 8601 string. Instead got: 1504784461

Any idea how to get past this?

Comment: The error is telling you that it cannot recognize what you're feeding it as a date object, which probably means that your `moment.unix(timestamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY")` line is returning something other than a date object (my guess is that after you 'format' it becomes a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of fiddling this works:

```js
var albumTimeStamp = albumToDisplay.album_date;
var albumDateFormatted = moment.unix(albumTimeStamp).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
var albumDateISO = moment(albumDateFormatted).toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment's `format` method returns a string, so that's not what you need. It also seems that `mdDatePicker` converts the date internally so you don't even need moment for this to work. All you need to do:

```
this.albumDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  album_title: [albumToDisplay.album_title],
  album_date: [albumToDisplay.album_date]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @everest. Unfortunately I get the same error here. If I use my code above, or yours on a standard text input it'll bring back the time stamp (when using your code), or the formatted string (when using my code). However, trying to integrate it into the 'md-datepicker' produces the same error.

Comment: I've also added an update to my question with some 'progress'.

Comment: From the looks of it you just need to convert your unix time stamp to a JavaScript date